# Google Cloud Storage Bucket Contents

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, json-api, php-curl

```
<?php

$url="https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/sts_bucket/o?key=xxx&project=xxxxx
$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json_response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($json_response == FALSE){
    echo "cURL error: " . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

echo "</pre>";
echo $json_response;
echo "</pre>";


?>
```

I am makin following request to google cloud storage to get the bucket information. But it shows the following error:-

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", 
"message": "Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.list access to 
 bucket sts_bucket.", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" 
 } ], "code": 401, "message": "Anonymous users does not have 
storage.objects.list access to bucket sts_bucket." } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include an authorization: header.
For an example try running:

```
gsutil -d ls
```

and look in the debug output for the authorization: header it includes. The output will look something like this:

```
... 
connect: (www.googleapis.com, 443)
send: 'GET /storage/v1/b?project=your-project&fields=nextPageToken%2Citems%2Fid&alt=json&projection=noAcl&maxResults=1000 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.googleapis.com\r\ncontent-length: 0\r\nauthorization: Bearer your-oauth-token\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate\r\naccept: application/json\r\nuser-agent: apitools gsutil/4.27 Python/2.7.6 (linux2) analytics/enabled\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
...
```

Hopefully this makes it clear what you need to change in your code.

Comment: I would recommend against trying to hand-code OAuth2-based authentication because the access token needed for performing operations is valid for a limited time and you need to acquire a new token when the token expires (see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started). Instead it's easier to use a library that handles OAuth2 for you. I don't have experience with PHP OAuth2 libraries but you probably can find a usable library from one of these: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+oauth2